# Updating a table entry tells me the table does not exist in a procedure

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that attempts to update an order if the stock is sufficient, however when the update is attempted (but only if it is done within the procedure) I'm given the error

"
15:20:05 call plswork(@LatestOrder, 2, 20) Error Code: 1109. Unknown table 'Product' in field list  0.000 sec
"

So far I've attempted to see if there are any mistakes in table names and table keys. I've also tried to do the update outside of the procedure, here it works.

```
Delimiter ¤
create procedure plswork(
    in NewOrder INT,
    in ProductID INT,
    in PurchaseQuantity INT)
begin
    start transaction;

    insert into Order_items(Oid, Pid, Quantity)
    values (NewOrder, ProductID, PurchaseQuantity);

    update Product p
    set p.Stock = p.Stock - PurchaseQuantity
    where p.Pid = p.ProductID;

    if((select Product.Stock
        where Pid = ProductID) < 0) then
        rollback;
    else
        commit;
    end if;
end ¤
Delimiter ;


INSERT INTO Orders(Cid,Order_date, Order_status)
VALUES (1, '2040-01-31 12:11:00' , "SENT");

select @LatestOrder := max(Oid)
from Orders;

call plswork(@LatestOrder, 2, 20);
```

What can I do to fix my issue?

Comment: I think the error is from this query:  `select Product.Stock where Pid = ProductID`   (there's no FROM clause, so qualifying "Stock" with a table name is invalid).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the error is from the `UPDATE` statement.

I think the error is being thrown with this SQL statement:

```
 select Product.Stock where Pid = ProductID
```

There's no `FROM` clause, so qualifying `Stock` with table name `Product` is not valid.